# UseState array update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I get a crash when the state tries to push the first element.

```
export interface ISortedMessages {
sortedMessages: {
    error: Array<Message['message']>,
    warning: Array<Message['message']>,
    info: Array<Message['message']>,
}}
```

I want to sort the incoming messages as they enter into the useState

```
switch (message.priority) {
case 0:
    setStateMessages(previousMessages => ({ ...previousMessages, error: [...previousMessages.sortedMessages.error, message.message] }));
    break;}
```

Thank you in advance! If you believe there's a better way of resolving this, please let me know.

Comment: can you give us the error logs too? and please explain what the input and the expected output is like?

Comment: Yes! The error just reads: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'error').

I need the state to get populated by incoming messages, tagged as 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: You are updating an array, as you state, but your setStateMessages is not updating the main array.  If you have more than one index in that array, you will need to find the index you want, update the value, then update your state with that new array.

You can easily do this with `map()`, `filter()`, `find()`, and/or `some()`